# Pytest additional argument that allows tests run in parallel properly

Tags: python, pytest

I am using pytest and wish to use both `-s` (to disable all capturing) and `-n NUM` to allow multiple tests run at the same time. Each of them works well alone but when I use both of them together, I got error messages "redirected Stdin is pseudofile, has no fileno()", which I believe means that `-s` loses its function.

Would anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: You may get more helpful answers if you post the code in question, or a simplified version of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is [known](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/680) pytest-xdist issue, unfortunately.